# How can I make this into an IF OR function?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a few functions that take a certain woocommerce category on our WordPress website and change the 'add to cart' button links when products are in this category. Everything works fine, and it has been working for a few years now.

For the first time ever, we need it to apply this function to two different categories. It seems to be an instance that happens not very often, however, I need to figure out a solution.

I need the If statement to be an if, or statement if possible, and everything I've tried has broken my website.

```
function so_43372512_maybe_show_auction_link(){
if( has_term( '12917', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo ' <style type="text/css">
                .woocommerce div.product form.cart, .woocommerce div.product p.cart {
                display:none ; }
                .woocommerce div.product p.price, .woocommerce div.product span.price {
                display:none ; }
                .woocommerce div.product p.stock {
                display:none ; }
                .product_meta {
                margin-top:20px;
                }
            </style>';
    echo '<p>Click This Button To View The Lot         </p>';
    global $product; 
    $skusearch = $product->get_sku();
    echo '<a id="auction" style="font-size:100%;color:#fff;padding:.618em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;font-weight:700;" href="https://www.boggsequipment.com/auctions" target="blank">' . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'so_43372512_maybe_show_auction_link', 35 );
// Remove the price on archive pages (like shop) for 'auction' product category
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_price_from_archives', 9 );
function remove_price_from_archives(){
    global $product, $post;

    // Only for 'auction' product category
    if ( has_term( '12917', 'product_cat' ) )
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
}

// Remove the displayed price and add-to-cart button on archive page for 'auction' product category
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_the_displayed_price_from_variable_products', 9 );
function remove_the_displayed_price_from_variable_products() {
    global $product, $post;

    // Only for 'auction' product category
    if ( has_term( '12917', 'product_cat' ) ){
        // remove product price
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
        // Add your custom "On Auction Now!" button
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'replace_add_to_cart_by_auction', 30 );
    }
}

// This function displays your custom button replacement in archive pages
function replace_add_to_cart_by_auction(){
    global $product;

    $skusearch = $product->get_sku();
    $style = 'style="font-size:70%;color:#fff;padding:.7em 1em;border-radius:3px;background-color:#ed1c24;font-weight:700;float:right;"';
    $href = 'href="https://www.boggsequipment.com/auctions"';

    echo '<a '.$href.' id="auction" '.$style.' target="blank">' . __ ( 'On Auction Now!', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>';
}
// Replace the displayed price and add-to-cart button on archive page for 'auction' product category
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'readd_the_displayed_price_from_variable_products', 9 );
function readd_the_displayed_price_from_variable_products() {
    global $product, $post;

    // Only for non 'auction' product category
    if ( ! has_term( '12917', 'product_cat' ) ){
        // replace product price
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'replace_add_to_cart_by_auction', 30 );
        // Add your custom "On Auction Now!" button
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
        //replace product price properly
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
    }
}
```

What I need is 'if ( ! has_term( '12917', 'product_cat' ) )' to have this include two different product categories. For example product category '12917' OR '12910'. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ! has_term( array('12917','12910'), 'product_cat' ) )
```

hope this help.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Never thought of just creating an array. Simple and effective. I will mark as the correct answer as soon as the time limit is up.